# Multiple inputs from one input request

Tags: pandas, input

Just need someone to tell me how to run an input variable 1-50 instead of writing out input1 =, input 2 = etc.

```
ap1 = input('Airport 1:').upper()
ap2 = input('Airport 2:').upper()
ap3 = input('Airport 3:').upper()


data = [['led1', ap1], ['led2', ap2], ['led3', ap3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['LedNum', 'AP'])

df.to_csv('airports.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list instead of one variable for each input. Maybe something like this:

```
ap_list = [input(f'Airport{i+1}:').upper() for i in range(3)]
data = [[f'led{i+1}', ap_list[i]] for i in range(len(ap_list))]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['LedNum', 'AP'])
df.to_csv('airports.csv')
```

Comment: Perfect! Just getting started, didn't even know about lists thankyou!